# remove extension in list python

Tags: python, os.walk

I have the following code whereby I would like to find all files in a certain folder (this folder contains .TIF files), then store these names in a .txt file which works so far. However, I don't want the extensions, of anything that would be in the folder.

```
import os, sys

f = [] 
b = os.walk('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\FOLDER')
for(dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in b:
    f.extend(filenames)
    break

def save_to_file(text):
    for name in f:
        with open('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\FOLDER\\test2.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
            myfile.write('\n'.join(text))
            myfile.write('\n')

save_to_file(f)
```

After comments, especially thanks to ShadowRanger, I changed it to the following which produced the same effect. Thank you everyone!:

```
import os

f = [e.name for e in os.scandir(r'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\FOLDER') if e.is_file()]
print('Saving file...')

def save_to_file(text):
    for name in f:
        with open('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\FOLDER\\test5.txt', mode='wt', encoding='utf-8') as myfile:
            myfile.write('\n'.join(text))
            myfile.write('\n')

save_to_file(f)
```

Comment: Side-note: Why are you using `os.walk` when the loop is broken after the first loop? Why not just replace loop with `f = [x for x in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\FOLDER') if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\FOLDER', x))]`, or if you're on 3.5+, use `os.scandir` to save the per file `stat`, `f = [e.name for e in os.scandir(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\FOLDER') if e.is_file()]`?

Comment: Not strictly related to your question (answers already below), but you should open file first and then start loop instead of opening/closing file N times inside loop.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm quite new to Python, so I'm not used to writing Pythonic yet..but this forum is really helpful :). I will try to implement your comments!

Comment: Can you remove your answer from your *question*? If the answer you came up is significantly different from the existing suggestions, you can always add it as an alternative answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the extension in a generator expression when you get the filenames with [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext). Change:

```
f.extend(filenames)
```

to:

```
f.extend(os.path.splitext(name)[0] for name in filenames)
```

**Update:** It looks like you're abusing `os.walk` to do file from directory separation (since you `break` in the first loop, so you're not actually walking a tree at all), when there are more direct ways to do this. You can replace all of this:

```
f = [] 
b = os.walk('C:\\Users\\username\\Desktop\\FOLDER')
for(dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in b:
    f.extend(filenames)
    break
```

on Python 3.5+ (or any version of Python after installing [the third party `scandir` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir) using `scandir.scandir` instead of [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir)), with the more succinct and somewhat faster:

```
f = [os.path.splitext(e.name)[0] for e in os.scandir(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\FOLDER')
     if e.is_file()]
```

which describes what you really want, and by using `os.scandir`, guarantees you don't have to individually `stat` each entry in the directory listing to check if it's a file.

If you're on older Python, and can't use the `scandir` package, at the cost of a `stat` (which `os.walk` would pay anyway on older Python), you can do:

```
f = [os.path.splitext(x)[0] for x in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\FOLDER')
     if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\username\Desktop\FOLDER', x))]
```

Comment: I should've known..you're awesome thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```
f.extend(filenames)
```

with something like this:

```
filenames_stripped = [os.path.splitext(file)[0] for file in filenames]
f.extend(filenames_stripped)
```

or even simpler:

```
f.extend([os.path.splitext(file)[0] for file in filenames]
```

More info on what [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) but it essentially splits the filename into 2 pieces. The first is the root, which is what you want.

Comment: Ah thank you very much, but I saw the answer by ShadowRanger first. You're also very awesome for helping :D